# Making every character on a web page the same width

Tags: html, css, fonts

Is there a font or CSS property that would give every character the same width without the need of drawing them yourself(`.ttf`)?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

How about Courier New? monospace?

http://www.ampsoft.net/webdesign-l/WindowsMacFonts.html

Comment: It does not work for following two characters: ▼, ▶. At least Chrome, IE and Firefox will give them different width.

Answer (score 77):

If you only need numbers to be equal widths, you can use `font-variant-numeric: tabular-nums;`. It's really useful for animating counters. Read more about it on [Mozilla web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-variant-numeric#numeric-figure-values).

Comment: I came here trying to remember the little-known CSS property, and disappointed this isn't the accepted answer, when it's clearly the best ;)

Comment: Same as previous comment. This answer needs to go higher up!

Comment: @HusseinDuvigneau this solution is not supported in IE

Comment: Nice!! Thank you! I was rendering numbered buttons in a table and couldn't figure out why the "1" button was narrower than the rest of them :) This is perfect!

Comment: this [tweet](https://twitter.com/sulco/status/1293862293139337217) shows an example of this

Answer (score 68):

CSS:

```
font-family: monospace;
```

HTML:

```
<tt>
```

Comment: would you please add some description?

Comment: FYI the **tt** tag is deprecated in HTML5

Comment: tt tag is HTML and is properly honored in github's hybrid HTML / Markdown ...  Good to know, for anybody interested.

Answer (score 26):

You could chose from any of the [freely available fixed width fonts](http://www.fontriver.com/basic/fixed_width/) and embed them in your site.

If you don't want to embed a font in your page, you could use the following to take whatever monospace (another term for fixed width) font is available:

```
font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
```

Comment: But, would every character have the same width? like "M" and "," both being 5px for example.

Comment: yes - that's what mono-spaced means. It's also why monospaced fonts are usually very unattractive.

Comment: @Jay - Yes. That is the whole point of a fixed width font. Each character takes the same amount of space so everything lines up.

Comment: @MichaelMullany `Consolas` isn't so bad.

Comment: As @MichaelMullany said, monospaced fonts are usually very unattractive, too "console" look&feel... Do you know any more friendly monospaced font?

Comment: Any idea if this will work with unicode characters like emojis?

Answer (score 9):

For certain cases, using the **pre** tag,(`<pre>text</pre>`), might fill your needs for monospaced (fixed width) text. It worked for me with **HTML5** + **Chrome** (current version). The `tt`element is deprecated.

However it appears the `<pre>` tag can only contain tags which are considered "**phrasing content**". See "**Content model**" section on the [w3 documentation for that tag](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-pre-element). You can click the link to see what elements are considered "phrasing content". Of course, each browser may support a looser version of the spec if you don't care about valid HTML or cross browser compatibility.

Comment: Indeed, as for today (January 2018) monospace is not correctly applied on Android versións of Chrome and Opera when using the `<pre>` tag. On Safari for iPhone 4S it seems to be working all right.

Answer (score 3):

There's a number of monospaced fonts that give equal width to each character.  [Courier and Courier New](http://web.mit.edu/jmorzins/www/fonts.html#monospace) are probably the most common, and should be available on pretty much every system.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use [lettering.js](http://daverupert.com/2010/09/lettering-js/), which would create a span element around each letter that you could then set a width to with css. This would probably only be advisable for small texts, though.