# PHP - normalize size of words composed of a same number of letters

Tags: php, words, normalize

Is there a trick in PHP to normalize the size of words, that are composed of a same number of letters ?

For example, I have these two words :
- Paparazzi
- Jukeboxes

On a Word document, "Jukeboxes" takes more place than "Paparazzi" whereas they are composed of 9 letters both.
How to make it to normalize the size of the two words ?

Thanks

Comment: And how is it supposed to do that? Make the font size smaler?

Comment: More html based but - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686754/making-every-character-on-a-web-page-the-same-width

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making every character on a web page the same width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686754/making-every-character-on-a-web-page-the-same-width)

Answer (score 1):

The visual size of a character is dependent on the font and therefore nothing php can change.
If you want every character to be of same (visual) size use a monospace font.